# Filtering a model only ends at 3rd character and returns blank

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I am just accepting a value of a model ('temp_dollars') and have a watch property to check the model and then filter it. However, everytime I write something in the input, it only stops at the 3 character and resets.

For example: 
When I write **123**,
The model value will then be  **123**
But when I write **1234**
It will return 0

```
Vue.filter('to_currency', (val) => {
  // let arr = val.toString().split('').reverse();
  // let num = 0;
  // let string = "";
  // let new_string = "";
  // let temp_arr;

  // _.forEach(arr, (value, key) => {
  //   if(key % 3 === 0 && key !== 0){
  //     string += ` ${value}`
  //   } else{
  //     string += value
  //   }
  // })

  // temp_arr = string.split(' ')

  // _.forEach(temp_arr, (value, key) => {
  //   temp_arr[key] = value.split('').reverse().join('')
  // })

  // return temp_arr.reverse().join().toString()

  let string = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'PHP' }).format(val).toString()
  return string.substr(4, string.length - 7)
})


watch : {
    temp_dollars (val) {
        this.temp_dollars = this.$options.filters.to_currency(val)
        console.log(this.temp_dollars)
        console.log(this.$options.filters.to_currency(val))
    }
}
```

I was hoping that when you type something in the input, it will automatically be filtered so **1234** will be **1,234** in the input box

** UPDATE **

This is my Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home--inner container mt-5">

        <!-- Errors -->
        <alert-error :isError="error"></alert-error>

        <!-- New Record -->
    <div class="form-row" v-show="!edit_record">
      <div class="col" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            v-bind:name="name" 
            v-bind:disabled="!new_record" 
            v-model="temp_name" 
            placeholder="Enter name..." 
            ref="name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Money</label>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            v-bind:money="dollars" 
            v-bind:disabled="!new_record" 
            v-model="temp_dollars" 
            placeholder="Enter dollars..."> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>_____________________</label>
            <div class="btn-group w-100">
                <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" @click="insertRecord" v-show="new_record">Convert</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success w-100" @click="newRecord" v-show="!new_record">New</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        <!-- Edit Record -->
        <div class="form-row" v-show="edit_record">
          <div class="col" >
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="edit_name" placeholder="Enter name...">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Money</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="edit_dollars" placeholder="Enter dollars..."> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>_____________________</label>
                <div class="btn-group w-100">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" @click="updateRecord">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Money Changer -->
    <money-changer :name="name" :dollars="dollars" @send:peso="convertToPeso" v-show="show_jumbo"></money-changer>

        <!-- History Table -->
    <history-table :history="history" @edit:history="editRecord" @delete:history="deleteRecord"></history-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Money from './Money'
    import Table from './Table'
    import Storage from './Storage'
    import Error from './layouts/Error'

    export default {
        // Components
        components : {
            'money-changer' : Money,
            'history-table' : Table,
            'alert-error' : Error,
        },

        // Data
        data () {
            return {
                name : '',
                temp_name : '',
                dollars : '',
                temp_dollars : '',
                error : false,
                history : [{id : 1,name : "Ernie",dollars : "1",peso : "54",}, {id : 2,name : "Jeash",dollars : "2",peso : "108",}, {id : 3,name : "Villahermosa",dollars : "1",peso : "54",}],
                history_item : [],
                id : 1,
                show_jumbo : false,
                new_record : false,
                edit_record : false,
                edit_name : '',
                edit_dollars : '',
                var : ''
            }
        },

        // Methods
        methods : {
            convertToPeso (peso_from_child) {
                this.peso = peso_from_child

                if(this.edit_record){
                    this.name = this.edit_name
                    this.dollars = this.edit_dollars
                } else{
                    this.name = this.temp_name
                    this.dollars = this.temp_dollars
                }


            },

            newRecord () {
                this.new_record = true
                this.temp_name = ""
                this.temp_dollars = ""
                this.show_jumbo = false
            },

            insertRecord () {
                this.show_jumbo = true

                this.history.push({
                    id : ++this.id,
                    name : this.temp_name,
                    dollars : this.temp_dollars,
                    peso : this.peso,
                })

            },

            deleteRecord (id){
                let index = this.history.findIndex((x) => x.id === id)
                this.show_jumbo = false
                this.history.splice(index, 1)
            },

            editRecord (id) {
                this.show_jumbo = false
                this.edit_record = true
                this.history_item = this.history.find((x) => x.id === id)
                this.edit_name = this.history_item.name
                this.edit_dollars = this.history_item.dollars
            },

            updateRecord (id) {
                this.temp_name = this.edit_name
                this.temp_dollars = this.edit_dollars
                this.show_jumbo = true

                this.edit_record = false

                this.history_item.name = this.edit_name
                this.history_item.dollars = this.edit_dollars
                this.history_item.peso = this.peso
            }
        },

watch : {
    temp_dollars (val) {
        // this.temp_dollars = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
    }
}
    }
</script>
```

** UPDATE **

Here is a simplier

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="val">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      val: 1234
    };
  },

  watch: {
    val(x) {
      this.val = Number(x)
        .toLocaleString("en")
        .toString();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you return a substring? Just return the whole string.

Comment: the whole string returns something like **PHP ####.00**, I am trying to get rid of the **PHP** as well as **.00**

Comment: You can try to do that without filter like this: `return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')`

Comment: @mare96, it's almost a go but it outputed like this **1,2,3,1,2,3,123**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the answer but I forgot to post it. The logic behind that is upon inputting, filter your v-model. Say you input '123' and the you add '4', then it will add a comma. This way it becomes a NaN. Therefore, in the computed property, you will filter your model to remove the comma.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm answering the question you are asking but the problem you seem to be solving is *format number as a currency, then remove currency symbol + fractional digits*.

If that is infact your problem then the solution is to change your formatting options to:

```
{
  style: "decimal",
  currency: "PHP",
  minimumFractionDigits: 0
}
```

Then you'll get `1,234` instead of `PHP 1,234.00`.

Update: The problem you describe getting 0 when you reach 1234 happens, I believe, because you set he value you are editing to the formatted value. You shouldn't do that. The formatted value is only for displaying.

If you want to give the user the perception that they are typing while the number is being formatted you can do something like this:

[Demo of hidden input](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-pnpiv)

Comment: I already got that part sir. The problem I am facing right now is that upon applying the filter on the model, it only ends at the third character and then returns blank

Comment: The filter method is fine. I logged the result in the console and is also fine. But when I apply it to the model, or even watch the model, upon inputting numbers, it ends at the third character

Comment: Could you show the Vue template, that would be helpful (update your question).

Comment: You should not write the formated number back to the model. You should use that only for display. When you write the formatted number back to the model the and you again run the `to_currency` on it the result will be NaN (Not a Number) thus it will fail.

Comment: If DO want to have the input field displaying what the user types as formatted, then the approach is to have a hidden input field (using CSS) and then displaying the format value on top of it so that it looks like the user is writing and the value if formatted at the same time.

Comment: That's what I was hoping also. But my mentor told me that during input, it will already filter the data, like masking or so

Comment: @MarielleMaeValdez I updated my answer in response. The issue is that you write the formatted string back to the value which is a number.

Comment: There should only be one input. Because the app is like you're entering money. The money you enter will automatically be filtered or watched

Comment: I understand that. See the demo I provided. You can see that I've just hidden the input text that isn't formatted and then show a formatted text on top. There are other ways to do this. Just a quick example to give you an idea.

Comment: ahhh okay sir. I have updated my question, sir. Uhmn, Why does it output NaN ? https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-m0nps?fontsize=14